# Removing built-in fields from wagtailstreamforms

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to remove the date, time, and multiselect fields from the wagtailstreamforms Admin page, such that they can't be used in any form site-wide.

I've tried calling `register('<field_name>', None)` to get rid of it, but this doesn't work:

```
# wagtailstreamforms_fields.py
from wagtailstreamforms.fields import register

@register('date', None)
@register('time', None)
@register('multiselect', None)
```

And creating an AppConfig to manually purge the wagtailstreamforms.fields._fields dict of the entries, but that doesn't seem to work either. I've made sure that this AppConfig is part of an app that loads after wagtailstreamforms.

```
class UpdatedConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_new_app'

    def ready(self):
        from wagtailstreamforms.fields import _fields

        _fields.pop('date')
        _fields.pop('datetime')
        _fields.pop('multiselect')

        for x in _fields.keys():
            print('{}: {}'.format(x, _fields[x]))
```

Is there any way to do this, hacky or otherwise? I'm using Wagtailstreamforms 3.1 and Wagtail version 2.2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to get what we needed by putting following code in the app's wagtailstreamforms_fields.py

```
# wagtailstreamforms_fields.py
from wagtailstreamforms.fields import _fields

if _fields.get('date'):
    del(_fields['date'])
if _fields.get('datetime'):
    del(_fields['datetime'])
if _fields.get('multiselect'):
    del(_fields['multiselect'])
```

So I guess you can say its a mix of the above 2 methods. It might be obsolete in the near future, see Stuart George's answer and its linked PR.

Answer (score 2):

Im the author of wagtailstreamforms and came across this. The ability to restrict what default form fields are loaded from the package is a great idea.

What I propose is to not load them from the the register method but to load them from a settings dict ie:

```
WAGTAILSTREAMFORMS_DEFAULT_FIELDS = {
    'singleline': 'wagtailstreamforms.fields.SingleLineTextField',
    'multiline': 'wagtailstreamforms.fields.MultiLineTextField',
    'dropdown': 'wagtailstreamforms.fields.DropdownField'
}
```

the defaults being all the internal fields. This way it can easily be overridden. We will leave the `register` decorator in place as to not break anything.

https://github.com/AccentDesign/wagtailstreamforms/pull/110

Please leave any comments / suggestions on the pr or the open issue. If you are happy with this will update docs, merge, release then can amend this as an answer.

Cheers, Stu.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer - I'll pass it along to the team. We ended up using a completely different method to remove the fields, but an 'official' method would be great!

Comment: What about an `unregister` method?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to override this template: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/block_forms/stream_menu.html

```
{% for child_block in child_blocks.list %}
    {% if child_block.name != "date" and child_block.name != "datetime" and child_block.name != "multiselect" %}
        <li><button type="button" class="button action-add-block-{{ child_block.name }} icon icon-{{ child_block.meta.icon }}"><span>{{ child_block.label }}</span></button></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```